# How to show specific text for duplicate row with 1 type column different

Tags: excel-formula

I would like to show if duplicate value but one type of column showing different text then return the expected result else remain the same

[image]

Seek for advise which formula is able to get this results

The formula does not work if there are multiple column between the data as image show as below:
[image]

**Latest**
Added more type in Column A and one more condition for column C and how to get the expected result in highlighted yellow
[image]

Comment: *Agent A* is the duplicate here, but how shall the formula determine which *Type* to favor for the output? It is unclear what values *Type* can take and by which rule the duplicates shall be consolidated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=IF(ROWS(UNIQUE(FILTER($A$2:$A$21;($E$2:$E$21=E2)*($D$2:$D$21=D2))))>1;"Cancel Leave";A2)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, I have try and the formula is work. However, I found a different scenario in my data list and I have updated the latest photo above. So want to check if there is any way to based on the content instead of duplicate? 

As some of the duplicate is without "Request Cancel Leave" and some duplicate is with totally New Request or Cancel Request

Comment: @cheng I don't really understand your needs, it is not shown in the picture of your question. What that picture shows, is what the formula does.

Comment: Hi @WeAreOne, yes the formula work, however when there are multiple column between the data then seems the formula not working.. Any Idea or advise on this?

I have added second image, you may take a look as above

Comment: @Cheng Just updated the answer. Formula now returns the values of your right yellow column.

Comment: Hi, I have updated a new version as per attached and would like to seek a new formula based on one more condition highlighted in blue and how to get the expected result in highlighted in yellow